# Build Checkov custom policy for VSCode extension

Tags: python-3.x, terraform, checkov

Checkov github repo (https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov) states how to build custom policies (terraform, docker) for checkov (cli). Is there a way we can build custom policy for VSCode as well, without buying the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You get 100 resources a month with the free tier on the platform, so you could build your custom policies for free that way and get them in VScode. Alternatively you could contribute them back to Checkov and they'll be there.